# if /else and Constructor

Tags: java

```
public static VerticalUtil getInstance(String pub,String subcategory) throws EnigmaException {
        if (util == null) {
            try {
                util = new VerticalUtil(pub,subcategory);
            } catch (EnigmaException e) {
                util = null;
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return util;
    }
```

I writing the method like that. but next time i call this method but util is not null so new VerticalUtil  Constructor is not work. I want to write the code if util is not null or null in if statement. if statement also need because of some condition. How do i change the code. please advice me. Thanks

Comment: how have you defined util?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: It is not clear what you asking.

Comment: you want `util` to be set to `null` if the initialization fail?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? if each time you call getInstance you want to have new instance, dont store it, if you want this to be lazy instantiate singleton, then it is ok, i you want to time to time create new instance, then add flag to your method (boolean create), you could also store your classes in map instead single variable, so you could have instance for each pub or subcategory. but first you need to know what exactly you want

Comment: yap util is Private Status util = null;

Comment: I declare util as a private status.

Comment: Question is i want to work util = new VerticalUtil() is a constructor.

Comment: but i declare util as a private status util = null;
so next time i call that getInstance method. it will not reach to new VerticalUtil(); cause util is not null. So, how do i change the if condition to reach new VerticalUtil().

Comment: @ZackSchulfler Rethink your question, clarify what you want to do in just one sentence. Then ask again and maybe we will be able to help you. Right now I don't think anybody gets what's your problem.